# Executar uma função a partir de uma classe

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Gostaria de saber se ha possibilidade de executar uma determinada função somente quando a *activity* for chamada por outra determinada *activity* específica. por exemplo: `Activity A` chamou a `Activity B`, neste caso executar a função `Y`, mas se a `Activity C` chamar a `Activity B` NÃO executar a função `Y`.

Comment: Não sei como você quer implementar isso, mas uma opção seria você passar parâmetros para a Activity C de quem a chamou e vincular a execução da função Y a condição desse parâmetro.

Comment: Obrigado meu nobre, consegui solucionar. Agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 3):

O que você pode fazer é passar valores para a `Activity` B. Verifique se quando for chamada, exista algum valor no `Intent` da mesma e trate o seu algoritmo. 
Mais ou menos assim:

**Activity A chamando a B:**

```
Intent i=new Intent(context, ActivityB); // como passar valor de activity para outra
i.putExtra("id", "seuValor"); // setando valor
context.startActivity(i); // startando a nova activity (B)
```

**Na Activity B:**
Verifica se foi passado o valor de `Activity` para outra `Activity`

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); // pegando o Intent
String id = intent.getStringExtra("id"); // pegando Valor do Intent
if (id == "seuValor")
    executarFuncao(id);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Diego!!!! Consegui resolver essa minha questão. Um abraço.

Comment: show de bola!!!